# Write list element into csv in prolog

Tags: csv, prolog, swi-prolog

i have to write into csv file with csv_write_file.
My actual code is:

```
insert(T, File, Data) :-
    Data = [X | Xs],
    X =.. [_, _, A, B, C],
    csv_write_file(File, [row(A, B, C)], [separator(0'\t)]),
    insert(T, File, Xs).
```

Data is a list like this :

```
[test(name, a, b, c), test(name, d, e, f), test(name, g, h, i)].
```

At the end, the file contain only last element of list --> `g h i`

but i want a file like this:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

Whats wrong with my implementation ? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this happens is because `csv_write_file/3` each time will *restart* writing to the `File`. So at the end, it will take `g`, `h`, `i` and write these to the file.

You can process the data in bulk to a list of `row/3`s and then write these to the file:

```
map_item(P, row(A, B, C)) :-
    P =.. [_, _, A, B, C].

insert(T, File, Data) :-
    maplist(map_item, Data, Rows),
    csv_write_file(File, Rows, [separator(0'\t)]).
```